# How do I Update CSS via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a function, I have a 'statuscolor' parameter  which allows the user to change the color depending on what they have chosen;

```
function ChangeUserColor(id, statuscolor) {
    var userId = $('#hdId').val();
    var code = "";

    if (userId == id) {
       code = $('<span class="status" style="background-color:' + statuscolor + '"></span>');
    }

    $("#divusers").append(code);
}
```

I am calling the function like;

```
ChangeUserColor(1, red);
```

My CSS is:

```
.status {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: red is not defined
    at init.chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected (Chat.aspx:105)
    at init.<anonymous> (hubs:25)
    at init.f.<computed>.<computed> (jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9)
    at init.dispatch (jQuery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at init.v.handle (jQuery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jQuery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at init.triggerHandler (jQuery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
    at t.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9)
    at t.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9)
    at t.fn.init.dispatch (jQuery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

Comment: If `red` is a string value it should be enclosed in quotation marks: `ChangeUserColor(1, "red")`

Comment: All, **please don't answer this question**. It has been resolved as a typo and will not be useful for future readers and will be closed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add quotes and it would be fine.

Instead of

```
ChangeUserColor(1, red);
```

Use

```
ChangeUserColor(1, "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

`red` should be a string `ChangeUserColor(1, 'red');`
here is an article about most common errors https://medium.com/@Iren.Korkishko/10-most-common-javascript-errors-dfdca7dbf3f5

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of an HTML element, use this syntax:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style
```

Change property and value and it will work.